# Strategy to avoid truncated label in shiny plots

Tags: r, shiny

Plots generated with `renderPlot()` in shiny apps differ in dependence to zoom-settings of the browser.
That is the reason why I ran into problems with truncated labels (see screenshots).

[image]
[image]

My question is: What is the best strategy to avoid this problem **and** increase image quality?

- save the plot as tempfile and use `renderImage()` [(like in this tutorial)](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html)?
- a workaround with an .svg file?